# Using SynonymFilterFactory with more than one dictionary

Tags: solr

Right now SynonymFilterFactory only allows to use one dictionary. I am wondering in indexing time if there is a way to use different dictionary depending on some metadata of a document (for example a category of a document). I feel like this should be doable if I override something in the indexer side? One way is to create a separate index/core based on the metadata but I hope to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do what I want at this point other than creating a separate core.